# How Do I Fix "Missing secret_key_base for 'production' environment" Deploying With Capistrano Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, deployment, capistrano, devops

I have to deploy a Rails API to AWS EC2.

I'm following this tutorial: https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/18.04#ruby

But I'm getting stuck on:

```
01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec rake db:migrate
01 rake aborted!
01 ArgumentError: Missing secret_key_base for 'production' environment, set this string with rails credentials:edit
```

when `cap production deploy`

How should I generate the key?

Where should I put it?

What I do I have to config to this get working?

Need details that I not finding anywhere.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Solved by `rails new app`

Copying master.key and credentials.yml.enc to my app

Commiting to repo

Added this line to `config/deploy.rb`:

```
set :linked_files, %w{config/master.key}
```

copy manualy the key to my ec2 on `path/to/app/shared/config/master.key`

And this problem was solved